# Objects are not valid as a React child found: object with keys {cca2, currency, callingCode, region, subregion, flag, name}

Tags: react-native

I am using component with AppPicker that selects a country then passes the **selected country** to another component through **navigation.navigate('component', { parameter: parameter}**), my problem is, I am getting **Objects are not valid as a React child**. the AppPicker's onselect method returns an array of objects as shown below and I have a function that extracts only the country name, the country name is stored in **country state** and I pass that to another component for display. Can anyone help with this problem. my components are shown below:

**Covid.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import CountryPicker from 'react-native-country-picker-modal'

export default function App(props) {

  const [country, setCountry] = useState(null) ;

  const getCountry = (country) => {
    return country.name;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => props.navigation.navigate('CovidCountryData', { selectedCountry: country})}> */}
      <Text>
          Welcome to Country Picker !
      </Text> 
      <CountryPicker  
         withFilter
         onSelect={(country) => {
          const countrySelect= getCountry(country)  
          setCountry(countrySelect);
          console.log(countrySelect);
          props.navigation.navigate('CovidCountryData', { selectedCountry: country})
         
        }}
       />
     {/* </TouchableOpacity> */}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

the **onselect** returns the array shown below

```
Object {
  "callingCode": Array [
    "213",
  ],
  "cca2": "DZ",
  "currency": Array [
    "DZD",
  ],
  "flag": "flag-dz",
  "name": "Algeria", =================> this is the country name I am extracting..
  "region": "Africa",
  "subregion": "Northern Africa",
}
```

**CovidCountryData.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

export default function CovidCountryData(props) {

    //console.log(props.navigation)
    let Country = props.navigation.getParam('selectedCountry'); //selectedCountry
    console.log(Country) ;
    
    return (
        <>
        <Text>You have selected the country shown below</Text>
        <Text>{Country}</Text>
      </>
    )
}
```

Comment: The console.log from CovidCountryData is printing the name of that country correctly?

Comment: When I try to console.log it in CovidCountryData it throws the error mentioned above, when I console.log in Covid.js it displays the correct country selected. I finding very hard to get past this error(above).

Comment: Tried to consol.log it throwing this error: ``` Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {cca2, currency, callingCode, region, subregion, flag, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead```

Comment: Did you try to remove this part  `<Text>{Country}</Text>` from CovidCountryData? Because I suspect that what you're trying to display is not a string, but an object. When you pass that country, here 
 `props.navigation.navigate('CovidCountryData', { selectedCountry: country})`, it may take the object returned from onSelect and not the state you wanted

Comment: @dianaqq I am here for guidance what do you think I should do? I tested the selected country in COVID.js, it is country name, I have function that extracts country name.. why do you think it would turn into objects that is what I do not understand

Comment: It is not turning it into object. You are in the scope of a function which uses the same name for the items it returns as you used for your state. Look at this example https://imgur.com/a/vryKMAd

Comment: Please guide me by example if can, I am little bit lost with last link you gave me in the previous comment

Comment: Please check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you are sending through the navigation the whole `country` object received from the `onSelect` function inside your `CountryPicker`, because the variable shares the same **name** as the one you're keeping in state. Refactor it this way to understand the changes:

```js
<CountryPicker  
         withFilter
         onSelect={(selectedCountry) => {
          const countrySelect= getCountry(selectedCountry)  
          setCountry(countrySelect);
          console.log(countrySelect);
          props.navigation.navigate('CovidCountryData', { selectedCountry: country}) // before even if you sent the country as param here, it wasn't the country from your state, but the one which is now called selectedCountry
         
        }}
       />
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I got past the first problem, but now the parramater passed to CovidCountryData.js is showing null for some reason.